# How to compare a users last use to current date?

Tags: objective-c, compare, nsdate

I would like to store a user's last use of the application and compare it with the current date.

According to the compare I would like to pop a notification on the screen.

How and where do I implement the code of saving the last date? (not in ApplicationWillTerminate as i read in another thread here)
How and where do I implement the code of reading that value?

(It should be a NSDate and use an if statement of course..)

Comment: Try to add the current date in a plist. In another day, compare the date w/ the last item in the file. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which has been built just for these kinds of things (it's a persistent key value storage with some limitations). Here is a quick snippet:

```
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// Write current date & time
[sharedDefaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastUsed"];
[sharedDefaults synchronize]; // This makes sure your changes are written to disk

// Read date & time
NSDate *lastStart = [sharedDefaults objectForKey:@"lastUsed"];
```

Where you want to place this depends on what exactly you would like to measure.

Comment: Tnx!
I saved the date with "applicationDidEnterBackground" and I used the read command in my viewDidLoad. now i will calculate the difference with timeInterval and output the notification accordingly.

Now, when I kill the app with the double click on the home btn and hold the icon, I can't re-open the app :-\ it puts "(lldb)" in the debug area at the xcode and the app dosent load anymore (untill I "Build & Run" again) Does it have to do with something I just did?

Comment: That has nothing to do with your recent changes. When you kill the app in the simulator your debug process is still running and attached to the killed simulator process, thus preventing you from restarting the app. Remove the debug connection before trying to restart (Google is your friend :))